# Insert into table only if select statement shows less than 2 rows

Tags: sql, count, insert

**I have table like that:**

| id | document_id | category_id | is_main_category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1765 | 210 | 181 | 0 |
| 1764 | 210 | 179 | 1 |
| 1763 | 201 | 179 | 1 |
| 1762 | 209 | 181 | 0 |
| 1761 | 209 | 179 | 1 |
| 1754 | 211 | 182 | 0 |
| 1753 | 211 | 180 | 1 |

I need to select:

```
SELECT * FROM `documents` WHERE document_id = 210;
```

And if the number of rows is less than 2 I would like to insert into table one more row, like that:

```
INSERT INTO document_category (document_id, category_id, is_main_category)
VALUES (210, 181, 0);
```

Could you please help me to merge those 2 constructions.

Comment: As per question guidelines, please do not post images. Convert it to text instead. Pls share you table schema, provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: Your question is much too vague. Please show the sample input before your inserts and the expected result afther them and explain the possible cases in detail. Use tables with text, don't add images or links. You also missed to tag your DBMS. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Simply put `INSERT INTO document_category (document_id, category_id, is_main_category)` before @gotkn's SELECT below.

Comment: The table screenshot has been replaced by coded table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can build upon this:

```
INSERT INTO document_category (document_id, category_id, is_main_category)
SELECT 210, 181, 0
FROM documents
WHERE document_id = 210
GROUP BY document_id
HAVING COUNT(*) < 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly, this should be what you looking for.

```
INSERT INTO 
    document_category(document_id, category_id, is_main_category)
SELECT 
    210, 181, 0
FROM 
    dual
WHERE
    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM documents WHERE document_id = 210) < 2;
```

Comment: This is just a worse variation of the answer because it is unclear whether OP use an Oracle DB.